# Why am I unable to answer calls from the lock screen on my Lumia 520?

Tags: lumia, lock-screen, calls

I purchased a 520 for my elderly mum. She finds answering a call quite difficult.

1. Press power
2. Swipe up
3. Tap **Answer**

My friend has a 620 which has the **Answer** and **Reject** buttons directly on the lock screen. Is there any way to get this on the 520?

Comment: I don't think step 1. is necessary, the display should activate automatically with an incoming call. On my 620 I do have to do step 2. and 3. as well. You might be able to disable the lockscreen to skip step 2.

Comment: Are you sure this is happening? It is almost impossible!

Comment: If this does happen in 620, then don't worry it might be an issue with 620 and not 520. :) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "Press power button" is necessary.

When you get an incoming call:

- If your phone is locked, slide up, then tap Answer or Ignore.
- If your phone is unlocked, tap Answer or Ignore.